# how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?

Tags: html, css

how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?
i also want to remove left and right paddings, plz manipulate my code as my desire.
how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?how can i fit my navbar menu on my page how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?how can i fit my navbar menu on my page?

```html
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<style>
/* Pure CSS3 Multi Level Drop Down Navigation Menu */
/*             By www.Bloggermint.com            */



#nav {  position: relative;    /*position of navbar right and left*/
        left: auto;
     float: left;
    font: 12px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
     border: 1px solid #121314;
     border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow:visible;
 line-height:10px;       /* change the border height  of the menu*/
        left: -2%;
   

        
        
        
 
}

#nav ul {

    list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    
 
}

#nav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
 color:#d4d4d4;
     padding: 5px 21.5px;  /* change the width of whole menu*/
 text-decoration: none;
     background:#3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        
        
       
 
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
     color:#FFF;   /* change tabs font hover color */
     background:#3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
        
        

}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color:#FFF;        /*  change the drop down font color*/
   background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        
       
}



#nav li ul {
 overflow:visible;
     background:#3C4042;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     left: -999em;
     margin: 29px 0 0;        /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
     position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
     z-index: 9999;
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        
      
        
       
}

#nav li:hover ul {
     left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
     background: none;
     border: 0 none;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 198px;       /*  change the border drop down menu border size*/
     box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        
        
}

#nav li li ul {
     margin:-1px 0 0 197px;  /*change the parent drop down list position, Right, Left*/
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     visibility:hidden;
      
}

#nav li li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
   
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
   
}





#nav ul ul li:last-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
     
       
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
       
       
}

header {
  border-top: 0px solid gold !important;              /*move header pic up and down*/
  margin-top: -43px !important;
}


</style>

<header style="position: relative; top: 6px;">
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Books</a>
<ul>  
     <li><a href="#">By Author &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ashfaq Ahmed</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Wasif Ali Wasif</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Abu Yahya</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/poetry-books.html">Poetry Books &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Allama Iqbal</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mir Taqi Mir</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mirza Ghalib</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Faiz Ahmed Faiz</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ahmed Faraz</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mohsin Naqwi</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ibne Insha</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Parveen Shakir</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Bano Qudsia</a></li>
     
</ul>
</li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/islamic-books.html">Islamic Books</a></li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Knowledge Books</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Computer Books</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Programming Books</a></li>
     
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Authors & Scholars</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html">Moulana Tariq Jamil</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din Shah</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/ghulam-muhammad-dard_29.html">Ghulam Muhammad Dard</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Something New</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Our Vision</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 

<li><a href="#">Sofwares</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/softwares.html">Antivirus</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Registered Apps <font size="1">  &#9658; </font> </a>

  <ul>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>


<ul>
<li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
<li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
</ul>






</li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
  <li><a href=https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.4</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Deep Things</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">AlhamduLillah</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Who We Are</a></li>


</ul>

</div></header>


</!doctype>
```

Comment: Text language, like the use of `plz` is not recommended in Stack Overflow(SO). Please change them.

Comment: OK, I am very sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry! Everyone make mistakes. Just remember the advice :)

Comment: @Faisal take a look of answers, you need to add your header display inline and remove left resize some ul li and all seem to be good.

Answer (score 0):

you **header** need to **display inline** and you dont need the left position just commented.

```html
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<style>
/* Pure CSS3 Multi Level Drop Down Navigation Menu */
/*             By www.Bloggermint.com            */

header{
  display:inline;
}
#nav {  position: relative;    /*position of navbar right and left*/
        left: auto;
     float: left;
    font: 12px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
     border: 1px solid #121314;
     border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow:visible;
 line-height:10px;      /* change the border height  of the menu*/
        /*left: -2%;*/
   

        
        
        
 
}

#nav ul {

    list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    
 
}

#nav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
 color:#d4d4d4;
     padding: 5px 21.5px;  /* change the width of whole menu*/
 text-decoration: none;
     background:#3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        
        
       
 
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
     color:#FFF;   /* change tabs font hover color */
     background:#3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
        
        

}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color:#FFF;        /*  change the drop down font color*/
   background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        
       
}



#nav li ul {
 overflow:visible;
     background:#3C4042;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
     border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     left: -999em;
     margin: 19px 0 0;        /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
     position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
     z-index: 9999;
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset; 
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        
      
        
       
}

#nav li:hover ul {
     left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
     background: none;
     border: 0 none;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 157px;       /*  change the border drop down menu border size*/
     box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        
        
}

#nav li li ul {
     margin:-1px 0 0 197px;  /*change the parent drop down list position, Right, Left*/
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
     visibility:hidden;
      
}

#nav li li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
   
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
   
}





#nav ul ul li:last-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
     
       
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
 -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
       
       
}

header {
  border-top: 0px solid gold !important;              /*move header pic up and down*/
  margin-top: -43px !important;
}


</style>

<header style="position: relative; top: 6px;">
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Books</a>
<ul>  
     <li><a href="#">By Author &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ashfaq Ahmed</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Wasif Ali Wasif</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Abu Yahya</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/poetry-books.html">Poetry Books &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Allama Iqbal</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mir Taqi Mir</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mirza Ghalib</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Faiz Ahmed Faiz</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ahmed Faraz</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mohsin Naqwi</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ibne Insha</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Parveen Shakir</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Bano Qudsia</a></li>
     
</ul>
</li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/islamic-books.html">Islamic Books</a></li>

     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Knowledge Books</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Computer Books</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Programming Books</a></li>
     
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Authors & Scholars</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html">Moulana Tariq Jamil</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din Shah</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/ghulam-muhammad-dard_29.html">Ghulam Muhammad Dard</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Something New</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Our Vision</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 

<li><a href="#">Sofwares</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/softwares.html">Antivirus</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.2</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Registered Apps <font size="1">  &#9658; </font> </a>

  <ul>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>


<ul>
<li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
<li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
</ul>






</li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
  <li><a href=https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.4</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Deep Things</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">AlhamduLillah</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Who We Are</a></li>


</ul>

</div></header>


</!doctype>
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all write html properly, You missed to start and close
>   `<html>` and you're closing `<!doctype>`

Let's come to CSS, why you added margin in minus, that is making your navigation on top with negative. and the last one change `float:left` to **`display:block`** on `ul li a {}`

*`{margin: 0};` this will reset margin of all html tags.*

```css
/* Pure CSS3 Multi Level Drop Down Navigation Menu */


/*             By www.Bloggermint.com            */

#nav {
  position: relative;
  /*position of navbar right and left*/
  left: auto;
  float: left;
  font: 12px calibri, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #121314;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 10px;
  /* change the border height  of the menu*/
  left: -2%;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 5px 21.5px;
  /* change the width of whole menu*/
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59, 63, 65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72, 76, 77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75, 77, 77)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59, 63, 65) 9%, rgb(72, 76, 77) 55%, rgb(75, 77, 77) 78%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59, 63, 65) 9%, rgb(72, 76, 77) 55%, rgb(75, 77, 77) 78%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover>a {
  color: #FFF;
  /* change tabs font hover color */
  background: #3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
}

#nav li ul a:hover,
#nav ul li li:hover>a {
  color: #FFF;
  /*  change the drop down font color*/
  background: #5C9ACD;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61, 111, 177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80, 136, 199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92, 154, 205)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61, 111, 177) 17%, rgb(80, 136, 199) 51%, rgb(92, 154, 205) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61, 111, 177) 17%, rgb(80, 136, 199) 51%, rgb(92, 154, 205) 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#nav li ul {
  overflow: visible;
  background: #3C4042;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  left: -999em;
  margin: 29px 0 0;
  /* change the position of drop down menu, up and down.*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
  background: none;
  border: 0 none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 198px;
  /*  change the border drop down menu border size*/
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav li li ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 197px;
  /*change the parent drop down list position, Right, Left*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
}

#nav ul ul li:last-child>a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child>a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0
}

border-top: 0px solid gold !important;

/*move header pic up and down*/


}
* {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>

  <header>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">By Author &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ashfaq Ahmed</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Wasif Ali Wasif</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Abu Yahya</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/poetry-books.html">Poetry Books &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Allama Iqbal</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mir Taqi Mir</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mirza Ghalib</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Faiz Ahmed Faiz</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ahmed Faraz</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Mohsin Naqwi</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Ibne Insha</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Parveen Shakir</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Bano Qudsia</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/islamic-books.html">Islamic Books</a></li>

            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Knowledge Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Computer Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Programming Books</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Authors & Scholars</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html">Moulana Tariq Jamil</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/pir-naseer-ud-din.html">Pir Nasir Ud Din Shah</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/ghulam-muhammad-dard_29.html">Ghulam Muhammad Dard</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Something New</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Our Vision</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Sofwares</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/softwares.html">Antivirus</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Registered Apps <font size="1">  &#9658; </font> </a>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font size="1"> &#9658;  </font></a>


                  <ul>
                    <li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2A</a></li>
                    <li><a href='https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html'>SUB-CATEGORY 2B</a></li>
                  </ul>






                </li>
                <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href=https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Level 2.4</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Level 2.5</a></li>
 </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Deep Things</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">AlhamduLillah</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lighthouse786.blogspot.com/p/coming-soon.html ">Who We Are</a></li>


</ul>

</div></header>


</html>
```